# how to remove digits or numeric characters from the string

Tags: android, string, replace

I have A small string which include digit for example

```
 "1 Al-Fâtihah"
,"2 Al-Baqarah"
,"3 Âl-'Imrân"
,"4 An-Nisâ'"
,"5 Al-Mâ'idah"
,"6 Al-An'âm"
,"7 Al-A'râf"
,"8 Al-Anfâl"
```

I want to remove digits from the string.working on android java

Comment: replaceAll() method of String class with regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the digits are only at the beginning of the `String` you could do it like this:

```
String res = string.substring(2, string.length);
```

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro Roaro.. i think Gopal Rao tell the best method

Comment: It depends on what you need to do. If the digits are always at the first character like the example you have given, mine solution works better, otherwise it's not a good one

Answer (score 3):

use `String.replaceAll(String,String)` method...

ex:

```
    String s = "awhefqo1234akwfn";
    String string = s.replaceAll("[0-9]", "");// prints awhefqoakwfn
```

here `[0-9]` indicates a regular expression which replaces all digits with a empty String

Comment: o sorry it tells me that "You can accept answer with in 2 minutes ". sorry i am new here. I will carry it in my mind for the next time

Answer (score 1):

Use `replaceAll()` method of `String` class.

```
string.replaceAll("\\d*$", "")
```

Comment: thank you very much Regex is the best way to remove specific characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "abcd123bcd";
s = s.replaceAll("\\d", "");
```

This will do the trick